# Maximal interval of existence for $x'=\frac{xt}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, initial-value-problems

I want to find the maximal interval of existence for $$x'=f(x,t)=\frac{xt}{\sqrt{x^2+1}},\ x(0)=1$$ and I want to use a theorem I found in one of my books. It is a certain statement of boundary behaviour of maximal solutions which I couldn't find in a wikipedia article to link. So just to make sure we are on the same page I will provide the theorem:

> Let $D\subseteq \mathbb R\times \mathbb R^n$ be a domain and $f:D\to\mathbb R^n,\ (t,x)\mapsto f(t,x)$ be continuous and locally Lipschitz with respect to $x$. For $(\tau,\zeta)\in D$ let $\lambda:]a,b[\to\mathbb R^n$ be a solution of the IVP $$x'=f(t,x),\ x(\tau)=\zeta$$ Then $\lambda$ is a maximal solution to the IVP iff one of the conditions hold:
>
> 1. $a=-\infty$
> 2. $a>-\infty$ and $\limsup_{t\to a}||\lambda(t)||=\infty$
> 3. $a>-\infty,\partial D=\emptyset$ and $\lim_{t\to a}\text{distance}(\partial D,(t,\lambda(t)))=0$
>
> Replacing the $-\infty$ with $\infty$ yields the conditions for $b$ so I will not list them here.

Now back to the problem: Since $f$ is continuously differentiable with respect to $x$ it is clear that $f$ is locally Lipschitz and therefore we have a unique maximal solution to the IVP with I will call $\lambda:\ ]a,b[\to\mathbb R$. The argument for $a$ should be the same as for $b$ so I will only care about the first one. Obviously we have $\partial D=\emptyset$ so (3.) is not an option and we only need to take care of (2.). So let's assume $a>-\infty$, then I am using $$f(t,x)\leq\text{sgn}(x)t$$ to obtain $$\limsup_{t\to a}|\lambda(t)|=\limsup_{t\to a}|\lambda(0)+\int_0^t\lambda'(s)ds|=\limsup_{t\to a}|1+\int_0^t f(s,x)ds|\leq$$ $$\leq\limsup_{t\to a}|1+\text{sgn}(x)\int_0^t sds|=|1+\text{sgn}(x)\cdot\frac{a^2}{2}|<\infty$$ so only option (1.) is left and the same goes for $b$, so in total we have that the maximal interval of existence is $\mathbb R$. Is my reasoning correct here? And if not, what is wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: You can say that $|f(t,x)|\le |t|$, but the signed version is wrong in 50% of the domain.

Comment: Apart from your free (which means partially wrong) use of the absolute value, your solution approach is correct. $|x(t)-1|\le\frac12 t^2$ can be shown.

Comment: Yes, I've just seen that as well. But it shouldn't matter really as I can use the triangle inequality and standard estimation of integrals to pull the absolute value under the integral to get $\dots\leq1+\int |f|$, right?

Comment: This is just a comment that you can solve this DE exactly (well, sort of, if you allow taking an inverse function).  If you write $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}\ \frac{dx}{dt}=t,$$ you can see that $$\int_{x(0)}^{x(t)}\frac{\sqrt{u^2+1}}{u}\ du=\frac{t^2}{2}.$$
That is,
$$\sqrt{x^2+1}-\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}\right)=\frac{t^2}{2}+1-\frac{\ln(2)}{2}.$$
The function $g(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1}-\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}\right)$ is a bijection from $(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, so
$$x(t)=g^{-1}\left(\frac{t^2}{2}+1-\frac{\ln(2)}{2}\right).$$

Comment: As I said, the idea and the general result are right, but the single steps are wrong. If $x$ and $t$ have opposing sign, then $f(t,x)>sign(x)t$. Both sides are negative, so $f$ is closer to zero, which is captured in $|f|\le|t|$. If you actually do it like in the comment, then the steps seem to become right too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\le 1$ gives
$$
|f(t,x)|\le |t|\implies |x(t)-x(0)|\le\int_0^t|f(t,x)|\,dt\le\frac{|t|^2}2
$$
so that the solution to the IVP, where it is defined, satisfies
$$
1-\frac12t^2\le x(t)\le 1+\frac12t^2.
$$
Per the cited possibilities for the behavior at the end points of the maximal domain, this excludes any finite end points.